# C++ Creating a function to get distance between two points

Tags: c++, function, object, distance

In my program I have created a constructor called `Point` with two values. I also have a `set`, `get`, `scale` and `translate` function. I'm trying to create a function that allows me to get the distance between the object and another point. I'm have trouble with it though any help would be brilliant.

```
#ifndef POINTMODEL
#define POINTMODEL
#define POINTDEB UG

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    Point(void);
    Point(double anX, double aY);
    ~Point();

    void setPoint(double anX, double aY);

    double getX();
    double getY();

    double scaleX(double theX);
    double scaleY(double theY);
    void translate(double theX, double theY);

    void distance(const Point& aPoint);

protected:
private:
    double theX;
    double theY;
};

inline Point::Point(void)
{
    theX = 1;
    theY = 1;
    cout << "\n The default constructor was called" << endl;
}

inline Point::Point(double anX, double aY)
{
    cout << "\n regular constructor called";
}

inline Point::~Point()
{
    cout << "\n the destructor was called" << endl;
}

inline void Point::setPoint(double anX, double aY)
{
    theX = anX;
    theY = aY;
}

inline double Point::getX()
{
    return theX;
}

inline double Point::getY()
{
    return theY;
}

inline double Point::scaleX(double theX)
{
    return theX;
}

inline double Point::scaleY(double theY)
{
    return theY;
}

inline void Point::translate(double offSetX, double offSetY)
{
    cout << "X is translated by : " << offSetX << endl;
    cout << "Y is translated by : " << offSetY << endl;
}

inline void Point::distance(const Point& aPoint)
{
}

#endif
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "Point.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "\n main has started" << endl;

    //Point myPoint;
    Point myPoint(1, 1);

    myPoint.setPoint(1, 1);

    cout << "\n The value for X is : " << myPoint.getX() << endl;
    cout << "\n The value for Y is : " << myPoint.getY() << endl;

    cout << "\n X scaled by 2 is : " << myPoint.scaleX(2) << endl;
    cout << "\n Y scaled by 2 is : " << myPoint.scaleY(2) << endl;

    myPoint.translate(2, 3);

    cout << "\n main has finished" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've not actually said what's wrong, and are you sure you need the `inline` keyword, I mean, if you're compiling for a wii then fine but otherwise it's likely redundant.

Comment: Why can't you do it? Do you know the algorithm (formula) to compute a distance between two points in the euclidean plan? Or is it an implementation issue? Please note that Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem_ or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah it's implantation. I heard about using get functions from the values but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: `inline double Point :: scaleX( double theX){
return theX;
}` is suspicious and should probably be more like `double Point :: scaleX( double x){
return m_x *= x; 
}` or even a void function, I mean should that return anything at all? And the distance between two points would be something like `double Point::Mag( const Point& p )
{
 return std::sqrt( std::pow(m_p.x - p.x, 2) + std::pow(m_p.y - p.y, 2) );
}`

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your `Point::getX()` and `Point::getY()` functions `const` like so:

```
inline double Point::getX() const
{
    return theX;
}
```

If they are not `const` you cannot call them when the parameter is a `const` reference.

Then the distance is (changed return from `void` to `double`):

```
double distance(const Point & aPoint) const
{
    const double x_diff = getX() - aPoint.getX();
    const double y_diff = getY() - aPoint.getY();
    return std::sqrt(x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff);
}
```

I have deliberately not used `std::pow` since the exponent is 2.
You also need to include `<cmath>` for `std::sqrt`.